# API function call in Swift returning invalid JSON response though the functions are running successfully

Tags: php, swift, codeigniter

Only JSON response in returned in invalid format. The functions in the API are running successfully.

```php
public function registertoken_post(){
        $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $dataDB = json_decode($json, true) ;

        $email = $dataDB['email'];
        $token = $dataDB['token'];


        $check = $this->body_model->registerToken($email,$token);


        if($check == 0)
        {
            $response['message'] = "Token edited successfully";
            $response['status'] = "Success";
            $log = json_encode($response);
            echo $log; 
        }
        else if($check == 1)
        {

            $response['message'] = "Unable to edit Token";
            $response['status'] = "Fail";
            $log = json_encode($response);
            //return $log;
            echo $log; 

        }
        else
        {
            $response['message'] = "Email not Found";
            $response['status'] = "Fail";
            $log = json_encode($response);
            echo $log; 
        }

    }
```

Result in Swift:

Error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Response JSON: `<68747470 3a2f2f31 39322e31 36382e31 2e323034 3a383038 302f7376 2f7b0a20 20202022 6d657373 61676522 3a202254 6f6b656e 20656469 74656420 73756363 65737366 756c6c79 222c0a20 20202022 73746174 7573223a 20225375 63636573 73220a7d>`

Expected JSON:

```
{
    "message": "Token edited successfully",
    "status": "Success"
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is? Is the API outputting the correct format (JSON), but when accessing the API via your swift application the response is in a different format?

Comment: Yes, Output is in different format

Comment: It is clear the _Response JSON_ is not a valid JSON, which means The functions in the API are **NOT** running successfully. Your server side code may have some debug output showing `http://192.168.1.204:8080/sv/`, find and remove the line.

Comment: @OOPer Response JSON: <68747470 3a2f2f31 39322e31 36382e31 2e323034 3a383038 302f7376 2f>

Comment: You need find which line of your PHP code is generating the response.